# How do I change the 12 hour format in django?

Tags: django, django-models, time, django-admin, django-timezone

I have a DateTimeField in my model.

When I add this field to admin.py , then the format shows as 4:00 pm , how can this be changed to 16:00?

`creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,)`

If I do this

```
def time(self):
return self.creation_date.timezone().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

that time field is not sorted

Comment: Normally that is *not* the task of Django, that is the locale of the user, and the template is formatted accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the format with the `DATETIME_FORMAT` setting: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#datetime-format

> Default: 'N j, Y, P' (e.g. Feb. 4, 2003, 4 p.m.)
>
> The default formatting to use for displaying datetime fields in any
> part of the system. **Note that if USE_L10N is set to True, then the
> locale-dictated format has higher precedence and will be applied
> instead. See allowed date format strings.**

Answer (score 0):

You can change the time format in Django admin by creating a custom admin model and overriding the `date_hierarchy` attribute. Here's how you can do it:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import YourModel

@admin.register(YourModel)
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    date_hierarchy = 'creation_date'
    date_hierarchy_drilldown = False

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        self.date_hierarchy = request.GET.get('dh', 'creation_date')
        return super().changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
```

In this code, `YourModel` should be replaced with the name of your model. This will change the date format in the Django admin interface to a 24-hour format.

As for the sorting issue, Django admin should automatically sort the `DateTimeField` in descending order. If it's not sorting correctly, you might want to check if there's any custom sorting applied in your admin model.

If you want to sort by the `creation_date` field, you can add it to the `ordering` attribute in your admin model:

```py
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ordering = ('-creation_date',)
```

This will sort your model instances by `creation_date` in descending order in the Django admin interface.